# Make Room DAO return LiveData<Cursor>

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-room, android-livedata

Do you know how to make Room DAO return a `LiveData<Cursor>` ?

---

I need to request a lot of objects from my DB.
Because of memory issues, I don't afford an heavy object list, I need a Cursor.
Of course data could be updated and I need to be notify when it occurred.
So a `LiveData<Cursor>` should be a good solution.

But, when I compile this :

```
@Dao
public interface FooDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM foo")
    LiveData<Cursor> getFoo();

}
```

Android Studio says to me :
`Error:(22, 22) error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type`

Well... Please do not tell me we can't get notify of data updates with a Cursor :/

Comment: you can only get `Cursor`, not `LiveData<Cursor>`, what you need, however, could be done with `MediatorLiveData` (or `android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations`)

Comment: Not sure if I got it... Could you please show me some code ?

Comment: "Because of performance issues, I don't afford an heavy object list, I need a Cursor" -- what makes you think that your code for pulling data out of a `Cursor` is faster than Room's code for pulling data out of a `Cursor`? After all, *something* is pulling data out of the `Cursor`, otherwise the `Cursor` is useless.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yeah my bad, I would say "memory issues". I assume to have a Cursor in memory is better than have an instance of a list containing 500 instances of object.

Comment: I rather doubt that it will be a significant problem. For a 500-row `Cursor`, I would expect the overhead of 500 POJOs to be ~2000 bytes (plus 4 bytes for the `List`). If your memory is so tight that ~2000 bytes is a problem, you have bigger issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare it depends, `Room` returns simply `ArrayList` and not any "sophisticated" `List` implementation, if the `Cursor` contains 1M entries for example it means that it calls `add` method one million times - using a raw `Cursor` would be much faster in that case

Comment: @pskink: My guess is that the time to load the data from disk will swamp the time it takes to create the POJOs.

Comment: @CommonsWare not really as `SQLiteCursor` extends `AbstractWindowedCursor` at most 1Mb `CursorWindow` will be filled, with `room` and with big dataset it will be filled many many times (even if you dont need it at once) - `Cursor` is better in that case as it loads data "on demand"

Comment: @pskink: That does not eliminate disk I/O. The only scenario in which it does is if the consumer of a `Cursor` does not iterate over all the rows and so the full result set is never loaded from disk. If that is a common scenario, you have bigger issues, such as usability, as you are querying for much more data than the user is capable of consuming. Regardless, based on the description, IMHO this is a premature optimization.

Comment: Actually, right now my app have to handle 65 000 items. And it keeps growing. So I am not sure how to do the Transformations... Could you show me some code, it will be very helpfull...

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, I have to create a LiveData from a DAO just to get notified from DB changed and another one, a LiveData<Cursor>, created from a Transformations with the LiveData notifier ? @pskink

Comment: it seems i was too fast with `Transformations` but `RoomDatabase#getInvalidationTracker` is most likely what you want: call `addObserver` on it and you will be notified any time when content of some tables changes - so this is the good point for updating your `LiveData<Cursor>` variable (by calling `LiveData#setValue` method)

Comment: and? did `Observer#onInvalidated` make a trick?

Comment: Yeah ! It seems to work for me.

Comment: But do not forget to remove the observer on onDestroy(). (Not sure for now)

Comment: actually you should use `postValue`, not `setValue`, also you can use `addWeakObserver`

Comment: I think addWeakObserver is restricted to same library package.

Comment: indeed, i missed `@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)`

Comment: So, will `FooDao#getFoo()` execute synchronously ? If yes, I have to request the data in another thread ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @pskink in comments, here is my solution:

```
public class DbLiveData<T>
        extends MutableLiveData<T> {

    public interface DataLoader<T> {

        T loadData();

    }

    @NonNull
    private final InvalidationTracker.Observer mDatabaseObserver;

    @NonNull
    private DataLoader<T> mDataLoader;

    @NonNull
    private final Executor mExecutor;

    public DbLiveData(@NonNull String[] tables, @NonNull Executor executor, @NonNull DataLoader<T> dataLoader) {
        mExecutor = executor;
        mDataLoader = dataLoader;
        mDatabaseObserver = new InvalidationTracker.Observer(tables) {
            @Override
            public void onInvalidated(@NonNull Set<String> tables) {
                loadData();
            }
        };
        loadData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        DB.get() // I get my DB from a Service Locator
                .getInvalidationTracker()
                .addObserver(mDatabaseObserver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        DB.get() // I get my DB from a Service Locator
                .getInvalidationTracker()
                .removeObserver(mDatabaseObserver);
    }

    private void loadData() {
        mExecutor.execute(
                () -> postValue(mDataLoader.loadData())
        );
    }

}
```

I created a LiveData which manage an `InvalidationTracker.Observer`. You just have to pass a `DataLoader` to constructor, this one have to get the `Cursor` from the database.
Like this :

```
new DbLiveData<Cursor>(
    new String[] { "foo" },
    getExecutor(), // Provide an Executor
    () -> DB.get() // I get my DB from a Service Locator
            .fooDao()
            .getFoo()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use instance of RoomDatabase if using Room 2.x

```
RoomDatabase appDatabase;
...

public LiveData<Cursor> getCursorLiveData(){
    return appDatabase.getInvalidationTracker().createLiveData(new String[]{"table1","table2"}, true, ()->{
       Cursor cursor = ...;
       return cursor;
    }
}
```

table1, table2 are tables to observe.
provide true as second param if you want the computeFunction(last function arg) will be done in a transaction